# Experimenting with responsive, absolute positioned child div... (eek!)

Tags: css-position, responsive-design

So,

I have a fairly simple parent div containing two child divs, one is text (floated left), the other contains an image (floated left against the first child)...the float of the second is kind of irrelevant (I just don't want it to drop down below). But what I want to achieve is for the image to sit in the bottom right of the parent and STAY there. At the same time I want it to be part of a fluid grid and for the distance from the bottom/right to also be responsive.

I tried absolute positioning (with an extra parent added around it to position:relative), which just didn't work at all...it could only be left/top positioned which then wouldn't work in %'s.

I then tried adding padding (top, left) instead of using positioning, thinking I could maybe push it into place...which worked great for keeping it to the right (pushing left), but obviously didn't work for the bottom (pushing from the top), as this value needed to increase as the screen decreased rather than the other way around (doh!).

Just wondering if anyone has any ideas or creative solutions?

I know I'm trying to do a number of tricky things all at the same time!!

Comment: Take a look at this article and the demo, it may help you come up with a framework that will eventually solve your issue: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/22/device-agnostic-approach-to-responsive-web-design/

Comment: Great question. I too am having an issue like this and haven't found any answer.